# Как анализировать пакеты на уровне Java?

Tags: java, linux, трафик

Возможно ли анализировать трафик (приходящие пакеты) на уровне Java?

Если возможно, то как и правильно ли так делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы порекомендовал PCAP https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap
Используй jNetPcap (http://jnetpcap.com/) 
PCAP является стандартным решением для собственных таких программ

Comment: Есть ли русская документация к jNetPcap?

Comment: сомневаюсь. переводчики нынче неплохо переводят